# How to run GWT's Super Dev + sourcemaps using the Showcase sample

Tags: gwt, source-maps, gwt-super-dev-mode

I'm looking for a way to run superdev mode + source maps with the GWT's 2.5 Showcase projects.

I've followed the following instructions:
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/superdevmode
http://blog.daniel-kurka.de/2012/07/mgwt-super-dev-mode.html

I've created a new Web Application Project on eclipse that uses gwt-2.5.0.rc1, and generated some sample code (Hello server).

I was able to run the code server on port 9876 and directing him to my src folder.
Navigated to my app, pressed the 'Dev Mode On' bookmarklet. Recompiled the test project,
it recompiled successfully, but failed with the following exception in eclipse:

```
JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(String, Object, Class<?>[], Object[]) line: 91    
        Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Drilling down the exception, I'm getting

```
__gwt_getProperty([string: 'user.agent']): Property 'user.agent' of object  is not a function
```

and

```
[ERROR] [test] Failed to load module 'test' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11' at localhost:50072
```

I'm looking for a detailed example on how to run it on the Gwt's 2.5 Showcase sample.

**Update**:
When I've tried it on the Mail sample, I've noticed that my code server doesn't output the **Mail.html** file. Instead this is the output from the code server:

```
mail (GWT Code Server)

Messages from the last time this module was compiled.

Output Files

(From the last successful compile.)

3FB1F1BBB0C7AED7089C2E77BAB03277.cache.js
clear.cache.gif
compilation-mappings.txt
mail.devmode.js
mail.nocache.js
```

No Mail.html file. this might help for diagnose.

Comment: This seems strange: JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(String, Object, Class<?>[], Object[]) line: 91    
        Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException. What do you mean by "run in eclipse"? Might you accidentally be mixing "classic" dev mode with Super Dev Mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing link was adding the user agent in the *.gwt.xml file.

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari" />
```

Comment: Perhaps this has to do with: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7458